# how can I change the value of a booleanfield from static file using checkboxes

Tags: python, html, django

I've just started using django and I'm not so familiar with it. This is my problem, I simply want to tick a checkbox and change the value of a booleanfield in the model which is default=false to true

I'm trying to create a function from views.py, but if there is any way to do it directly from the static file where my checkbox is that would do the work for me either

***This is my views.py***

```
def check(request):
    check = AddToCart.objects.get(orderd = request.GET['orderd'])
    check.is_active = True
    check.save()
```

***This is the checkbox***

```
Check: <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="checked">
```

***This is my model on models.py:***

```
class AddToCart(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    id_product = models.ForeignKey(Produkte, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    orderd = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   @property
   def cmimi_total(self):
       return self.quantity * self.id_product.cmimi
```

I have some objects inside AddToCart and I want to change the boolean values of each of them to True when the checkbox is ticked. I know my problem is just a basic one but as a newbie i could use some help. Thank You !

Comment: You can use jQuery ajax post for this

Comment: Is there only one checkbox or multiple?

Comment: your HTML page needs to POST the id of the object to mark as `orderd` (either when submitting the form, or using ajax). So your view should fetch the object based on this id and then set `orderd` to `True`. I don't know why you're fetching based on `orderd` (that would fetch all ordered objects) and I don't know why you're setting `is_active` since your model doesn't have that field.

Comment: Also why is your HTML a "static file"? How can it contain the products in the cart if it's static?

Comment: @SammyJ there is only one checkbox in the HTML file and when I tick it i want to  tick the booleanfield of each object inside AddToCart

Comment: Ok and what is `orderd` in  `check = AddToCart.objects.get(orderd = request.GET['orderd'])` is it the checkbox you are trying to access?

Comment: @SammyJ the field from AddToCart model i guess ?

Comment: Oh sorry, should have been more specific, I mean this `request.GET['orderd']` what is `orderd` here?

Comment: @dirkgroten i see youtube tuttorials saying i have to install django-multiselectfield package...I'm getting confused !

Comment: @SammyJ it gets 'orderd' field from the model..I've used the same way to get an object refering to it by id 'prod_delete = AddToCart.objects.get(id = request.GET['id'])' and then  'prod_delete.delete()'  to delete an object and thought of  doing something similar with the bolean value, after getting it like this i wanted to change the value from false to true, this is what ive been trying to do

Comment: @PàrísŹarka you need to take some more time learning the basics. How to make queries in Django and how to submit forms. And you've been looking at the wrong youtube tutorials. Most simple things can be done in django without 3rd party packages, and you should first have a good understanding of how django works before using 3rd party packages. They will just confuse you.

Comment: @dirkgroten i totaly get it ive just started learning django in like 2 weeks ago and python like a month ago

Comment: the official docs are well written and invaluable: [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) about queries and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) about forms.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks man i really appreciate your help and thank you for the guidance, its just my beginnig in django and i feel like I've dived into information that's why I'm also unclear in asking questions related to django

Comment: @PàrísŹarka sure, everyone has to start somewhere. Your question is too unclear to answer. An `AddToCart` model is strange as well, making it difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve. What does an `AddToCart` object represent? You normally have `Cart` and `Product` models (note the noun) and `add_to_cart` methods or views (note the verb) to add products to a cart. But what is "an addtocart"?

Comment: @dirkgroten all the records in my AddToCart model are shown as ' AddToCart object (number) ' on Django administration

Comment: That's the default way to represent a model object in Django. If you override the `__str__()` method, you can decide what you want to display when your objects are "printed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the checkbox and simply used a button to turn the boolean values in the model to **True**
**this is my views.py**

```
def check_out(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    checked = AddToCart.objects.filter(id_user = request.user, orderd = False)
    for a in checked:
        a.orderd = True
        a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/browse/')
```

and the button into html file

```
<a type="button" href="/check/" class="btn btn-ge style-4 btn-warning btn-sm" id="buy_button">Buy Now</a>
```